# How to prevent automatic JSON key type-casting

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

Good day to you all,

I've encountered a frustrating issue that seems to happens only in Chrome.

```
var response = '{"01":"January","02":"February"}',
    months = JSON.parse(response);

console.log(months['02']) // undefined in Chrome (my version is 24.0.1312.5 beta)
console.log(months[2]) // "February"
```

Firefox and Safari seem to handle this as expected, whereas Chrome is casting string-ish JSON keys to integers.

jQuery's parseJSON method has the same behaviour (I'm assuming it relies on the browser's JSON.parse method).

I'm fairly tied down to this specific API response format, so I'd rather not change the server's response. Is there a sane way to force Chrome to behave as expected?

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome 23.0.1271.64 .... don't use beta versions? ;)

Comment: Also works for me in Chrome 23.0.1271.64. Sounds like you've found a bug. Please log it here http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Jsfiddle if anyone is interesting: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/mevHy/. Also using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 and it works fine.

Comment: Works fine for me in `Chromium 22.0.1229.94 Ubuntu 12.10 (161065)`. Are you certain the native methods have not been overwritten

Comment: To find out, type `JSON.stringify` in the console, if it's something other than `function stringify() { [native code] }` then it's been overridden.

Comment: Works on my Chrome 25 Canary.

Comment: Works also here in Chrome 22.0.1229.94 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: AFAIK, beta isn't opt-in or -out. :)

JSON.stringify hasn't been overwritten it seems - I'll purge some extensions to see if they're possibly the culprit. I'll submit a bug report if the issue still persists.

Comment: Added a bug report at [http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160419](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160419).

Comment: @sheldonnbbaker: Out of curiosity, how is the key represented in a reviver function? `JSON.parse('{"01":"1"}', function(k, v) { console.log(k, typeof k); });` The first log should be `01 string`.

Comment: @sheldonnbbaker: I just posted an answer that may work as a temporary fix. You'd probably want to use some feature/bug detection so you only use it when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is there a sane way to force Chrome to behave as expected?"*

Not sure if you call this sane, but you can do some manipulation in a reviver function to patch it.

```
var response = '{"01":"January","02":"February"}',
    months = JSON.parse(response, 
                       function(k,v) {
                         if (this.constructor === Object && // is Object
                                               !isNaN(k) && // key is a Number
                                                  +k > 0 && //   from 1
                                                  +k < 1 && //     to 9
                                        k.charAt(0) !== '0') { // missing the '0'
                             this['0' + k] = v;    // manually assign the key
                             return;  // return undefined to prevent assignment
                         }
                         return v; // allow the assignment
                     });

console.log(months['02']);
```

Of course you'll likely need to tweak it a bit for your code so that you're not fixing things that don't need to be fixed.

You'll probably also want to test the browser before it runs to see if the fix is needed.

```
var needsJSONfix = !JSON.parse('{"01":1}')["01"];
```

---

```
months = JSON.parse(response, needsJSONfix ? fixFunc : null);
```

Comment: Thanks! That will certainly get me started. I didn't know about the reviver function argument. It's a shame that $.parseJSON doesn't act similarly.